# Numbering landscape tables does not work properly

Tags: tables, landscape

I have a problem with numbering landscape tables. The latex code below refers my table to as "Table 0.1". Could you please help me how can I get "Table 1"? Thank you!

```
  \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{booktabs,array,dcolumn}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{courier}
    \usepackage{color,xcolor}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{textcomp} 
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}


    \begin{document}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    \subsection{sub}\label{sub1}

    In Table~\ref{table:lstab}...

    \clearpage
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[t]
    \label{table:lstab}
    \caption{Title}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \hline
     A    & B & C & D & E & F  & G & H  & I     &  J     \\
    \hline  
    \end{tabular} 
    \end{table}    
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Put the \label after the \caption.